# Run ajax request after specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello I'm working on a website with a color slider that append a specific color page to the DOM after a slide change. I want people to still be able to go through the different slide pretty quickly and load the ajax page only if the user didn't change the slide for a specific time (for example 1000ms).
I tried setInterval, setTimeout and the ajax timeout parameter but it isn't working, it just adds requests to the call stack and after the timeout duration it appends the div 5 times.

Here's the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
     type:"POST",
     data: {
         action: "my_custom_color",
             post_link: post_ID
     }, success: function (response) {

         $('.color').prepend(response);

     },
})
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
colorsMonoSlider.events.on('indexChanged', () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            customizedFunction()
        }, 1000);
    });
```

But without filling the call stack (maybe emptying it at each call), the ajax request should only trigger once after the timeout, I can't disable the slider navigation or use `async: false` because as I said users need to be able to spam click to go through the slider fast.

Any tips welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want to `debounce` the event - there's various ways to do this or plugins available (numerous answers already on SO) - but essentially you store the `setTimeout` variable then cancelTimeout when the event is next called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cancel both your ajax call and timer functions before invoking again.
Assuming the customized function has the ajax call.

```
var xhr,timer;
    function customizedFunction(){
    xhr && xhr.abort();
    xhr = $.ajax({
             url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
             type:"POST",
             data: {
                 action: "my_custom_color",
                     post_link: post_ID
             }, success: function (response) {
        
                 $('.color').prepend(response);
        
             },
        })
    
    }


colorsMonoSlider.events.on('indexChanged', () => {
        timer && clearTimeout(timer);
        timer =  setTimeout(() => {
            customizedFunction()
        }, 1000);
    });
```